# Compacting and repairing a list of other databases

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Most of the resources I can find on this are from [several years past](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=48402) for older versions of Access and I am curious if best practices / new methods have come to light.

I have a table containing paths to a bunch of .mdb files that I wish to compact/repair. What is the correct way to do it? Is this still the right way?

```
Function Compact_DB(path as String, databaseName as String) 
    'for example, path = "C:\MyFiles\dev\" 
    'databaseName = "MyDatabase.mdb"

    'COMPACT CHOSEN DATABASE, TO TEMPORARY DATABASE NAME 
    DBEngine.CompactDatabase path & databaseName, path & "Spare1.mdb" 

    'DELETE OLD DATABASE 
    Kill path & databaseName

    'RENAME TEMPORARY DATABASE TO ORIGINAL NAME 
    Name path & "Spare1.mdb" As path & databaseName 

End Function
```

And then just run this in a loop over all my databases?

```
Sub Compact_All()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    rs.Open "select * from compactList", CurrentProject.Connection

    While Not rs.EOF
        call Compact_DB(rs("path"), rs("databaseName"))
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    rs.Close
    set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest that the process backs up the databases in question beforehand with a shell command with your favorite zip program, checking for ldb files of course.  Ron de Bruin has code that does this:  https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most things haven't changed. Yes, this is still an appropriate way to go about it.

Just remove the stray `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`. That shouldn't be there.

A further note: `Call` is deprecated. Use `Compact_DB rs("path"), rs("databaseName")` instead of that line with `Call`.

Also, `While ... WEnd` is mostly replaced with `Do While ... Loop`. But that's just style.

Do note that all databases need to be fully closed by all users. You can't compact open databases.

Comment: This is why I had the warnings line there though, since this is an automated database and it can't get stopped/held up in case it tries to compact something that's in use. Or should I be handling this differently?

Comment: Eh... `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` does nothing for that, it just suppresses warnings on action queries. You need error trapping code if you want to handle those.

Comment: If you want to do nothing and log nothing if an error occurs, you can go with that. I generally want to know if and when errors occur.

Comment: What's the correct way to log an error in that event?

Comment: That's a very broad and separate question. Generally, I have a logging table where I create an entry for each error, but I abort the function on errors. If you have a specific part (your loop) where you want to resume to the next iteration on an error, you can use `On Error Resume Next` before calling `Compact_DB`, and then check using `If err.Number <> 0 Then 'Do something and err.Clear` after calling it.